# Add variable to index match function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, concatenation, match

Need to add the variable as the range but cannot concatenate give error

```
Dim lr As Long
   lr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Dim arrayRangeAll As String  
Dim arrayRangeID As String  

  arrayRangeAll = Range("A2:L" & lr).Address  
  arrayRangeID = Range("A2:A" & lr).Address 

Range("N1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Client_Coorelation"  
Range("N2").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX(SMSv2!" & arrayRangeAll & ",MATCH(SMSv1!RC[-11],SMSv2!" & arrayRangeID & ",0),4)"
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but I'm not sure what you have the worksheet SMSv1. The string represents the following formula, from my sample worksheet of 20 rows.

`=INDEX(SMSv2!$A$2:$L$20,MATCH(SMSv1!RC[-11],SMSv2!$A$2:$A$20,0),4)`

```
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Dim arrayRangeAll As String
    Dim arrayRangeID As String

    arrayRangeAll = Range("A2:L" & lr).Address
    arrayRangeID = Range("A2:A" & lr).Address

    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Client_Coorelation"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(SMSv2!" & arrayRangeAll & ",MATCH(SMSv1!RC[-11],SMSv2!" & arrayRangeID & ",0),4)"
```

Comment: Did you add any modifications I am still getting the Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to work with, then I can update the answer. I'm unclear about the contents of SMSv1 and SMSv2, the two worksheets mentioned in the formula

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057812/type-mismatch-error-in-index-match-in-index-match-function

Comment: Try it also in above way but encountered another error

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second, because this may not be related to the variable, but to the formula you're assigning to the FormulaR1C1 property.

Using the example provided here: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html

Cell B3 contains the number 2 and the following VBA is used to add a formula to cell D4.

```
Sub foo_1()

    Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-2]*10"

End Sub
```

However using the style of formula from your example with the same values does not.

```
Sub foo_2()

    Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1-2]*10"

End Sub
```

and gives the 1004 runtime error.

[image: Run time error 1004]

Using the offset function achieves much the same and maybe more familiar to others:

```
Sub foo_3()

    Range("D4").Formula = "=offset(D4,-1,-2)*10"

End Sub
```