# Type mismatch Error in index match in index match function

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

> Type mismatch error

```
Dim lr As Integer

lr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("N2").Select
Range("N2").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("SMSv2").Range("A2:L" & lr), Application.Match(Sheets("SMSv2").Range("C2"), Sheets("SMSv2").Range("A2:A" & lr), False), 4)
```

Comment: Pick your choice: Either put in a valid `.Formula` (as you would write it in your worksheet) in your `Range("N2")` or return a result through VBA with VBA syntax. You can't input a `.Formula` using VBA syntax.

Comment: then how could i include it to the N2 cell

Comment: `Range("N2").Formula = "=INDEX(SMSv2!A2:L" & lr & ",MATCH.....etc`

Comment: You can also take out the line `Range("N2").Select`

Comment: JvdV it's working now brother you save my day thanks. I am new to vba have to learn lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lr As Integer   
lr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("N2").Select  
Range("N2").Formula = "=INDEX(SMSv2!$A$2:$L$" & lr & ",MATCH(SMSv1!C2,SMSv2!$A$2:$A$" & lr & ",0),4)"
```